# How to parse a string which holds date of format "Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM"?

Tags: java, android, datetime

#### what format can parse this dateString to a `Date`?

```
String dateString = "Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM";
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("");
    sdf.parse(dateString);              
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: use **MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a**

Answer (score 6):

The [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc includes a table that says (in part)

> ```
> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
> G         Era designator          Text            AD
> y         Year                    Year            1996; 96
> Y         Week year               Year            2009; 09
> M         Month in year           Month           July; Jul; 07
> w         Week in year            Number          27
> W         Week in month           Number          2
> D         Day in year             Number          189
> d         Day in month            Number          10
> F         Day of week in month    Number          2
> E         Day name in week        Text            Tuesday; Tue
> u         Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday) Number 1
> a         Am/pm marker            Text            PM
> H         Hour in day (0-23)      Number          0
> k         Hour in day (1-24)      Number          24
> K         Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number          0
> h         Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number          12
> m         Minute in hour          Number          30
> s         Second in minute        Number          55
> S         Millisecond             Number          978
> ```

I think you want a format like `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a`. Something like,

```
String userDateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
String dateString = "Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(userDateFormat);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs

```
Oct 01, 2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: And is there any sqlite query to compare such date, So that i could compare this date with my system date?

Answer (score 1):

The [Android reference for SimpleDateFormat has a table](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that can be used to build the format.

```java
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd, yyyy hh:mm:s a");
    sdf.parse(dateString);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if you want month as oct, jan etc

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

or for month digits you can use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this date format to convert datestring

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Formatting and parsing the various date formats we expect to encounter.**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Utility class for formatting and parsing the various date formats we expect
 * to encounter.
 */
public class DateUtils{
  private static final String TAG = "DateUtils";

  private static final SimpleDateFormat[] dateFormats;
  private static final int dateFormat_default = 7;

  private DateUtils() { }

  static
  {
      final String[] possibleDateFormats =
      {
        "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", // RFC_822
        "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm zzzz",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzzz", // Blogger Atom feed has millisecs also
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz", // ISO_8601
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmss.SSSz",
        "yyyy-MM-dd"
      };

      dateFormats = new SimpleDateFormat[possibleDateFormats.length];
      TimeZone gmtTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");

      for (int i = 0; i < possibleDateFormats.length; i++)
      {
        /* TODO: Support other locales? */
        dateFormats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat(possibleDateFormats[i],
          Locale.ENGLISH);

        dateFormats[i].setTimeZone(gmtTZ);
      }
  }

  /**
   * Parse a date string.  The format of RSS/Atom dates come in many
   * different forms, so this method is extremely flexible and attempts to
   * understand many different formats.
   *
   * Copied verbatim from Informa 0.7.0-alpha2, ParserUtils.java.
   *
   * @param strdate
   *   Date string to attempt to parse.
   *
   * @return
   *   If successful, returns a {@link Date} object representing the parsed
   *   date; otherwise, null.
   */
  public static Date parseDate(String strdate)
  {
    Date result = null;
    strdate = strdate.trim();
    if (strdate.length() > 10) {

      // TODO deal with +4:00 (no zero before hour)
      if ((strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 5).indexOf("+") == 0 || strdate
          .substring(strdate.length() - 5).indexOf("-") == 0)
          && strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 5).indexOf(":") == 2) {

        String sign = strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 5,
            strdate.length() - 4);

        strdate = strdate.substring(0, strdate.length() - 5) + sign + "0"
        + strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 4);
        // logger.debug("CASE1 : new date " + strdate + " ? "
        //    + strdate.substring(0, strdate.length() - 5));

      }

      String dateEnd = strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 6);

      // try to deal with -05:00 or +02:00 at end of date
      // replace with -0500 or +0200
      if ((dateEnd.indexOf("-") == 0 || dateEnd.indexOf("+") == 0)
          && dateEnd.indexOf(":") == 3) {
        // TODO deal with GMT-00:03
        if ("GMT".equals(strdate.substring(strdate.length() - 9, strdate
            .length() - 6))) {
          Log.d(TAG, "General time zone with offset, no change");
        } else {
          // continue treatment
          String oldDate = strdate;
          String newEnd = dateEnd.substring(0, 3) + dateEnd.substring(4);
          strdate = oldDate.substring(0, oldDate.length() - 6) + newEnd;
          // logger.debug("!!modifying string ->"+strdate);
        }
      }
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < dateFormats.length) {
      try {
        result = dateFormats[i].parse(strdate);
        // logger.debug("******Parsing Success "+strdate+"->"+result+" with
        // "+dateFormats[i].toPattern());
        break;
      } catch (java.text.ParseException eA) {
        i++;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Format a date in a manner that would be most suitable for serialized
   * storage.
   *
   * @param date
   *   {@link Date} object to format.
   *
   * @return
   *   Robust, formatted date string.
   */
  public static String formatDate(Date date)
  {
    return dateFormats[dateFormat_default].format(date);
  }
}
```

Or you can use below function for **Parse Date**..

```
 public static Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException {
        if (date == null || date.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return dateFormat.parse(date);
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date and Time Pattern                       Result

"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"      2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT

"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"                  Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"                            12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"             12 o'clock PM,Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z"                         0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"      02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"        Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"                     010704120856-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"        2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"      2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
"YYYY-'W'ww-u"                      2001-W27-3
```

Then you can convert your date string like the follow,

```
String dateString="Oct 1, 2015 12:00:00 AM";

try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd, yyyy hh:mm:s a");
    sdf.parse(dateString);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```